# Load a file into java and make an array from the data

Tags: java, arrays, file, load

I'm running into a problem whenever I try to take the data from a file and make an array and an int out of that data.
For this specific problem, we're given 17 data points in this style:

> 13 24 35 46 57 68 79 80 32 43 54 65 76 87 98 27
>
> 438

What I'm trying to do is make an array from the first row, and make the second row's single variable into an int.

How would I do this in java?

(for the problem, the second variable is what we check our results against, so I do want it as an int or atleast in it's own array)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this :

```
    String line = "13 24 35 46 57 68 79 80 32 43 54 65 76 87 98 27";
    String[] array = line.split(" ");
```

If you want to use this numbers for counting, you need to change them to integer.

```
    int[] intarray = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        intarray[i] = Integer.valueOf(array[i]);
    }
```

Comment: In thousands of examples when you search "How to read files in java"

Comment: I can find the other code in thousand of examples about *how to split a String into an array* and *how to go through an array* and *how to convert a String to an int*...

Comment: Read the authors question, he is not asking how to load/save files, he is asking how to make an array. Thats why I am answering to QUESTION. He only mentioned he is using files, not that he has problems using files.

Comment: I already read and posted a comment asking **what did he/she tried**.